# Unable to Save to database using Laravel Api

Tags: php, laravel, api, laravel-api

I have a many to many relationship setups in my laravel application

In my `User Model`, I have setup my  relationship

```
public function categories()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class)->withTimestamps();
}
```

In my 'Category Model` I have set up my relationship

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class)->withTimestamps();
}
```

In my `pivot` table named `categoryuser` I have this table schema

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('category_user', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->integer('category_id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

I am trying to add to save to my pivot table with this method

```
public function categoryUserapi (Request $request)
{

    $validatedData = $request->validate([
      'category_id' => 'required|array|min:3',
      'category_id.*' => 'integer',
  ]);
  $user = Auth::user();
  $user->categories()->attach($request->input('category_id'));

  return response(['user'=> $user]);
}
```

But it's not working, I don't know what I am doing wrong

In my api.php, I have this

```
Route::post('/onboardcategory', 'OnboardsController@categoryUserapi');
```

## UPDATE

It returned error

> "message": "Call to a member function categories() on null"

Comment: can you `dd($user);` after `$user = Auth::user();`? what's the result?

Comment: It returned Null

Comment: so it means there is no user logged in.

Comment: I am using postman to test. I was passing the user_id and category_id in the form to test. But i think that's where the error came from. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change Auth::user to User::find if you are passing user id

```
public function categoryUserapi (Request $request)
{


  $user = User::find($request->user_id);
  $user->categories()->attach($request->input('category_id'));

  return response(['user'=> $user]);
}
```